# How to add javascript string value to a value in hidden field in ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The closest I got to using in webpage was as follows:

```
<script>
$('#title').text(movie.title);
</script>
```

It works with lets say:

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

However I would like it to be used in the value in asp hidden field
eg

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="name" runat="server" Value="title" />
```

I am new to asp and javascript and jquery so any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$("[id$='name']").val(movie.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `jquery`:

```
$('#name').val(movie.title);
```

OR

```
$('#<%= name.ClientId %>').val(movie.title)
```

With `javascript`

```
document.getelementid('name').value=movie.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**Control.ClientID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the Client ID of ASP.NET Control. After that you can simply use [**ID Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Use (jQuery)

```
$('#<%= name.ClientId %>').val(movie.title);
```

With Vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById('<%= name.ClientId %>').value=movie.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..You have to set **clientidmode** property to **static**..

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="name" runat="server" Value="title" clientidmode="static"/>
```

After that set..

```
document.getelementid('name').value=movie.title;
```